# Efficient computation of moving linear regression with numpy/numba

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, numba

I am trying to create a moving linear regression indicator and I wanted to utilize `numba`. However, I am struggling with the latter part as I am lacking experience

Here's what I have so far utilizing `numpy`. It is working, however, without applying `numba` it is quite slow once you throw large arrays at it.

```
import numpy as np


def ols_1d(y, window):
    y_roll = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(y, window_shape=window)

    m = list()
    c = list()
    for row in np.arange(y_roll.shape[0]):
        A = np.vstack([np.arange(1, window + 1), np.ones(window)]).T
        tmp_m, tmp_c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y_roll[row], rcond=None)[0]
        m.append(tmp_m)
        c.append(tmp_c)

    m, c = np.array([m, c])

    return np.hstack((np.full((window - 1), np.nan), m * window + c))


def ols_2d(y, window):
    out = list()
    for col in range(y.shape[1]):
        out.append(ols_1d(y=y[:, col], window=window))

    return np.array(out).T


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.random.randn(
        10000, 10
    )  # function is slow once you really increse number of columns (let's say 1 mln)

    print(ols_2d(a, 10))
```

The indicator is actually computing a linear regression applying `np.linalg.lstsq` function (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) for a given window length. It than basically outputs the very last point of the regression line and moves on to the next range and computes the linear regression again. At the end of the day, `ols_1d` outputs the last point of every individual regression line putting it into an array.

Now, I need help in order to apply `numba` on top of it. I am not familiar with `numba`, but as far as my own trial and error goes, there might be an issue utilizing `nb.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view()`.

**EDIT: Follow-up question**

Using @aerobiomat's suggestion, I only needed to slightly modify `np.cumsum` in order to account for matrices rather then vectors.

```
def window_sum(x, w):
    c = np.cumsum(x, axis=0)  # inserted axis argument
    s = c[w - 1:]
    s[1:] -= c[:-w]
    return s

def window_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    sx = window_sum(x, w)
    sy = window_sum(y, w)
    sx2 = window_sum(x**2, w)
    sxy = window_sum(x * y, w)
    slope = (w * sxy - sx * sy) / (w * sx2 - sx**2)
    intercept = (sy - slope * sx) / w
    return slope, intercept
```

Now, let's create a 20x3 matrix, where columns represent individual time series.

```
timeseries_count = 3
x = np.arange(start=1,stop=21).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.random.randn(20, timeseries_count)

slope, intercept = window_lin_reg(x, y, 10)
```

This is working fine. However, as soon as I introduce some `np.nan`, I am running into some issues.

```
y[0, 0] = np.nan
y[5, 0] = np.nan
y[10, 2] = np.nan
```

In order to compute the rolling regression, I need to drop all `np.nan` in each column and compute it column-wise. This does go against vectorization, doesn't it?
Every column in the real dataset may contain a different number of `np.nan`. How to cope with that issue in a clever way? I need speed as the dataset may be quite large (10000 x 10000 or so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calculating the linear regression for each window, which involves repeating many intermediate calculations, you can compute the values needed by [the formula](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Edickey/courses/st512/pdf_notes/Formulas.pdf) for all windows and perform a vectorized calculation of all regressions:

```
def window_sum(x, w):
    # Faster than np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, w).sum(axis=0)
    c = np.cumsum(x)
    s = c[w - 1:]
    s[1:] -= c[:-w]
    return s

def window_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    sx = window_sum(x, w)
    sy = window_sum(y, w)
    sx2 = window_sum(x**2, w)
    sxy = window_sum(x * y, w)
    slope = (w * sxy - sx * sy) / (w * sx2 - sx**2)
    intercept = (sy - slope * sx) / w
    return slope, intercept
```

For example:

```
>>> w = 5      # Window
>>> x = np.arange(15)
>>> y = 0.1 * x**2 - x + 10
>>> slope, intercept = window_lin_reg(x, y, w)
>>> print(slope)
>>> print(intercept)
[-0.6 -0.4 -0.2  0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2  1.4]
[ 9.8  9.3  8.6  7.7  6.6  5.3  3.8  2.1  0.2 -1.9 -4.2]
```

Comparing with `np.linalg.lstsq()` and loops:

```
def numpy_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    m = len(x) - w + 1
    slope = np.empty(m)
    intercept = np.empty(m)
    for i in range(m):
        A = np.vstack(((x[i:i + w]), np.ones(w))).T
        m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y[i:i + w], rcond=None)[0]
        slope[i] = m
        intercept[i] = c
    return slope, intercept
```

Same example, same results:

```
>>> slope2, intercept2 = numpy_lin_reg(x, y, w)
>>> with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
...     print(np.array(slope2))
...     print(np.array(intercept2))
[-0.6 -0.4 -0.2  0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2  1.4]
[ 9.8  9.3  8.6  7.7  6.6  5.3  3.8  2.1  0.2 -1.9 -4.2]
```

Some timings with a larger example:

```
>>> w = 20
>>> x = np.arange(10000)
>>> y = 0.1 * x**2 - x + 10

>>> %timeit numpy_lin_reg(x, y, w)
324 ms ± 11.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit window_lin_reg(x, y, w)
189 µs ± 3.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

That's three orders of magnitude of performance increase. The functions are already vectorized, so there's little Numba can do. "Only" twice as fast when the functions are decorated with `@nb.njit`:

```
>>> %timeit window_lin_reg(x, y, w)
96.4 µs ± 350 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great. Note however that `n` is undefined in `numpy_lin_reg` and the parameter `w` is unused. Did you meant `numpy_lin_reg(x, y, n)` ? Besides this, I think `np.ones(n)` can be computed only once although the performance is already relatively good. I wonder if using `hstack` of a transposed `x` value would not be a better than `vstack` with a transposition.

Comment: Yes, the n->w change was a last minute change. I'm editing it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, the purpose of `numpy_lin_reg` was to follow the same implementation as in the question. But you're right, it would be fair to make the changes you suggest before comparing performance.

Comment: I accepted your answer as you clearly answered the original question. However, I edited and broadened my question in order to take into accounts time series containing ``np.nan``.

Comment: I find that, contrary to your note, stride tricks is faster and doesn't have an error with tiny floats. `def window_sum(x, w): return np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, w).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as an answer to @Andi's followup question where input data may contain nans.

These are the updated functions:

```
def window_sum(x, w):
    c = np.nancumsum(x)     # Nans no longer affect the summation
    s = c[w - 1:]
    s[1:] -= c[:-w]
    return s

def window_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    # Invalidate both x and y values when there's a nan in one of them
    valid = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    x[~valid] = np.nan
    y[~valid] = np.nan

    # Sums for each window
    n = window_sum(valid, w)    # Count only valid points in the window
    sx = window_sum(x, w)
    sy = window_sum(y, w)
    sx2 = window_sum(x ** 2, w)
    sxy = window_sum(x * y, w)

    # Avoid ugly warnings
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        slope = (n * sxy - sx * sy) / (n * sx2 - sx ** 2)
        intercept = (sy - slope * sx) / n

    # Replace infinities by nans. Not necessary, but cleaner.
    invalid_results = n < 2
    slope[invalid_results] = np.nan
    intercept[invalid_results] = np.nan

    return slope, intercept
```

Test with nans:

```
>>> w = 5      # Window
>>> x = np.arange(15.)
>>> y = 0.1 * x**2 - x + 10
>>> x[3] = np.nan
>>> y[7:12] = np.nan
>>> slope, intercept = window_lin_reg(x, y, w)
>>> with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
...     print(slope)
...     print(intercept)
[-0.59 -0.4  -0.21 -0.   -0.    0.1    nan   nan   nan  1.5   1.6 ]
[ 9.8   9.35  8.69  7.57  7.57  7.     nan   nan   nan -5.6  -6.83]
```

The version using `np.linalg.lstsq` and loops, only to compare results:

```
def numpy_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    valid = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    x[~valid] = np.nan
    y[~valid] = np.nan
    m = len(x) - w + 1
    slope = np.empty(m)
    intercept = np.empty(m)
    for i in range(m):
        window = slice(i, i+w)
        valid_ = valid[window]
        x_ = x[window][valid_]
        y_ = y[window][valid_]
        n = valid_.sum()
        if n < 2:
            slope[i] = np.nan
            intercept[i] = np.nan
        else:
            A = np.vstack((x_, np.ones(n))).T
            m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y_, rcond=None)[0]
            slope[i] = m
            intercept[i] = c
    return slope, intercept
```

Tested with the same data:

```
>>> slope2, intercept2 = numpy_lin_reg(x, y, w)
>>> with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
...     print(np.array(slope2))
...     print(np.array(intercept2))
[-0.59 -0.4  -0.21  0.    0.    0.1    nan   nan   nan  1.5   1.6 ]
[ 9.8   9.35  8.69  7.57  7.57  7.     nan   nan   nan -5.6  -6.83]
```

In order to use the new implementation with Numba, a couple of changes are needed:

```
@nb.njit
def window_sum(x, w):
    c = np.nancumsum(x)         # Numba needs SciPy here
    s = c[w - 1:]
    s[1:] = s[1:] - c[:-w]      # Numba doens't like -=
    return s

@nb.njit
def window_lin_reg(x, y, w):
    # Invalidate both x and y values when there's a nan in one of them
    valid = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    x[~valid] = np.nan
    y[~valid] = np.nan

    # Sums for each window
    n = window_sum(valid, w)
    sx = window_sum(x, w)
    sy = window_sum(y, w)
    sx2 = window_sum(x ** 2, w)
    sxy = window_sum(x * y, w)

    # No warnings here from Numba
    slope = (n * sxy - sx * sy) / (n * sx2 - sx ** 2)
    intercept = (sy - slope * sx) / n

    # Replace infinities by nans. Not necessary, but cleaner.
    invalid_results = n < 2
    slope[invalid_results] = np.nan
    intercept[invalid_results] = np.nan

    return slope, intercept
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask some follow-up questions? - Your function works fine when I insert ``x`` and ``y`` as ``1D`` vectors (your example). However, my data ``y`` is column-oriented matrix. Every column represents a time series for which I need to compute the rolling LinReg. That is, I would need to apply you function to every column of ``y``. This couldn't be intended, could it? That's why I inserted ``c = np.cumsum(x, axis=0)`` in your original answer. Can you use my 20x3 ``y`` matrix? ``x`` is just a column vector that could be broadcasted.