# Rolling Regression in Python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to implement a Rolling Regression in Python and failed to do so using the statsmodels 'MovingOLS'. In my data frame, the 'Year'  column specifies the year of the respective observation.

Now, I want to regress 'F1_Earnings' on 'Earnings' and 'WC' with a rolling 2-year-window, such that the forecast made in year 1998 for year 1999 is based on the 2 preceding years, 1997 and 1998, but I do not get a meaningful result, probably because I haven't understood how to set the `window` parameter properly. So how do I relate the `window` parameter to the 'Year' variable?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import seaborn
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS

d1 = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6], 'Earnings': [100, 200, 
400, 250, 300, 350, 400, 550, 700, 259, 300, 350, 270, 450, 340, 570, 340, 340], 'WC': 
[20, 40, 35, 55, 60, 65, 30, 28, 32, 45, 60, 52, 23, 54, 45, 87, 54, 65], 'Year': [1995, 
1996, 1997, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1996, 
1997, 1998], 'F1_Earnings': [120, 220, 420, 280, 530, 670, 780, 210, 950, 100, 120, 430, 
780, 210, 950, 100, 120, 430]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

y = df1['F1_Earnings']
features = ["Earnings", "WC"]
x = df1[features]

rols = RollingOLS(y, x, window=2)
rres = rols.fit()
params = rres.params.copy()
params.index = np.arange(1, params.shape[0] + 1)
params.head()
```

Comment: Here might be another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296498/efficient-computation-of-moving-linear-regression-with-numpy-numba/70304475#70304475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an issue you are running into is that `window (int): Length of the rolling window. Must be strictly larger than the number of variables in the model.` (as from the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS.html)).

Also the `window` is just the *count* of observations. So `window=2` will just use the two previous items in the list. This isn't going to work since you have a variable number of observations from each year.

Also you need to manually add an intercept (as a constant) if you want slope + intercept.

Given your variable number of records per year, I think a for loop is the only real option.

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

d1 = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
    'Earnings': [100, 200, 400, 250, 300, 350, 400, 550, 700, 259, 300, 350, 270, 450, 340, 570, 340, 340],
    'WC': [20, 40, 35, 55, 60, 65, 30, 28, 32, 45, 60, 52, 23, 54, 45, 87, 54, 65],
    'Year': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1996, 1997, 1998],
    'F1_Earnings': [120, 220, 420, 280, 530, 670, 780, 210, 950, 100, 120, 430, 780, 210, 950, 100, 120, 430],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
# df1 = add_constant(df1)
df1['intercept'] = 1

outcome = ['F1_Earnings']
features = ["Earnings", "WC", 'intercept']

result = {}
for year in df1['Year'].unique():
    current_df = df1[(df1["Year"] <= year) & (df1["Year"] >= (year - 1))]
    model = OLS(current_df[outcome], current_df[features]).fit()
    result[year + 1] = model.params
```